# How to exactly distort the perspective in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to distort with perspective an image and i want to set it on specific coordinates. I expect him to stand on them, but only the upper left corner stands correctly. Is it possible to make all the corners stand on the coordinates that I specify?
[image]

My code:

```
convert roof.jpg -matte -background none -virtual-pixel background  \
       -distort Perspective '0,0,541,286  0,1428,82,542  2000,1428,1137,549  2000,0,1306,203' \
       roof-pers.png
```

Example for output:
[image]

Comment: In the future, please provide full resolution and separate input images to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, thank you for advise

Answer (score 2):

You need to use +distort in ImageMagick to make it work. Note you can use %[fx:w-1] and %[fx:h-1] for the input.

[image]

```
convert roof.png -background none -virtual-pixel background +distort Perspective "0,0 541,286  0,%[fx:h-1] 82,542  %[fx:w-1],%[fx:h-1] 1137,549  %[fx:w-1],0 1306,203" roof-pers.png
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. But how can I get the output png with the same size as the original image ( in my example 2000x1428px) and this destorted image should be placed in exact coordinates. See example in my question

Comment: You need to specify coordinates that are consistent with the size you want. Or resize after the perspective. Perhaps I do not understand. You get the same size as the input with -distort. But I thought your issue was you wanted it to match the coordinates you specified. Please make your issue more clear. I do not understand.